# create nested dictionary using list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I would like to create a very long nested dictionay, but some instead of creatin new items, it just keep updating the same last item.

```
sessions = ['S0_DO','S1_DO','S2_DO','S3_DO','S4_DO','S5_DO']
groups = ['All','Aggregator','Non-Aggregator']
comparator = {}


for session in sessions:
    for group in groups:
        c = {
            "time" : "2019-09-20 10:30:00",
            session :{
                group:{
                    "std":0,
                    "mean":0,
                    "upper_limit":0,
                    "lower_limit":0,
                    "actual":0,
                    "anomaly":0
                }
            }
        }
        comparator.update(c)
```

all the sessions are created, but when it comes to groups, only the last item of the list is in the dictionary. it just updated instead of creating new one.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

output desired :

```
comparator = {
    "time" : "2019-09-20 10:30:00",
    "S0_DO" :{
        "All":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
        },
        "Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
            
        },
        "Non-Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0

        }
    },
        "S1_DO" :{
        "All":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
        },
        "Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
            
        },
        "Non-Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0

        }
    },
        "S2_DO" :{
        "All":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
        },
        "Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
            
        },
        "Non-Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0

        }
    },
        "S3_DO" :{
        "All":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
        },
        "Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
            
        },
        "Non-Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0

        }
    },
        "S4_DO" :{
        "All":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
        },
        "Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
            
        },
        "Non-Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0

        }
    },
        "S5_DO" :{
        "All":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
        },
        "Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0
            
        },
        "Non-Aggregator":{
            "std":0,
            "mean":0,
            "upper_limit":0,
            "lower_limit":0,
            "actual":0,
            "anomaly":0

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of input and desired output

Comment: Your top-level dict (the one you `update` can only hold one key for `time` and for each of the sessions, so the previous ones get overwritten with the last group. How should the result be structures exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration of the `group` loop, you overwrite the value of the `session` key with a new dict holding only that single group, thus all sessions end up with just the last group. You probably want to replace the inner loop with a dictionary comprehension.

```
comparator = {"time": "2019-09-20 10:30:00"}
for session in sessions:
    c = {
        session: {
            group: {
                "std": 0,
                "mean": 0,
                "upper_limit": 0,
                "lower_limit": 0,
                "actual": 0,
                "anomaly": 0,
            }
            for group in groups
        }
    }
    comparator.update(c)
```